# Rule about excessive (up and down) voting.

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

> Is there any rule about excessive (up and down) voting?

I'm asking this because someone upvoted 15 of my questions/answers in one minute. I'm not sure whether he did this in good faith or not, but certainly this will be considered a serial voting by the system and soon these votes will be reversed. I consider an abuse doing such things (voting irregularities?), and if there is no rule about this maybe it's time to be one.

**Update.** As I said, the system reversed the serial upvoting. I still think the users doing this should take a break for voting irregularities.

Comment: Voting and voting anonymity is sacred in the system, so the site moderators are not capable of seeing who voted on each question. There are, however, automated checks that occur each day that are generally very good at detecting serial up- and downvotes. So if this was a single user, I suspect that those votes will disappear in the next few days.

Comment: @mixedmath This is nothing new for me. What I'm proposing is to give a break to the users who are doing such things, and the admins can easily find out who has done this.

Comment: We do give warnings and suspensions for voting irregularities. These are taken quite seriously, perhaps even moreso since for almost all voting irregularity suspension we site moderators must involve the SE Community Team.

Comment: @mixedmath Good. But is this written somewhere on the site? That is, an user could find a rule about voting irregularities containing a reference to the excessive (up and down) voting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) answers your question:

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

> If such a voting pattern *continues* to happen between two users mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside of normal voting patterns, moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter; *intentionally* voting merely to reduce or inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.